# Difference between Google Cloud Platform and Google Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have this question about GCP and Firebase-firestore what is there difference? can call the data that is on firestore and connect it to GCP? or the other way around?

example if i have a users collection in firestore will i be able to pull it and connect it to GCP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same data in both situations.  The origin of access doesn't matter.

Read this: https://medium.com/google-developers/firebase-google-cloud-whats-different-with-cloud-firestore-40f1fc3e6d1e

Comment: Thanks for this. One more thing if i write a GCP functions will that work also on clound functions for firestore?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  There is one product called Cloud Functions, and there are tools to deploy functions using both Cloud and Firebase.  They both target the same product.  https://medium.com/google-developers/firebase-google-cloud-whats-different-with-cloud-functions-612d9e1e89cb

Comment: You might also want to start with an overview of the relationship between Firebase and Google Cloud.  https://medium.com/google-developers/whats-the-relationship-between-firebase-and-google-cloud-57e268a7ff6f

Comment: Actually I'm learning Firebase and its features specifically in firestore and searching for updated learning materials is there a resources you know like a video or article that is very comprehensive for beginner level? like where what are the pre-required knowledge so that I can understand clound functions? just a recomendation.

Comment: There are lots of resources out there: just do a web search.

Comment: If your original question was answered here, please mark the answer as correct. If you have further questions please post them separately.

Comment: thank you for your articles it give me alot of Idea's between them firebase and GCP

Comment: I was searching and there i see your comment https://www.quora.com/What-do-I-need-to-learn-before-learning-Firebase-Cloud-Functions

Comment: this has given me a rightful insights and been rereading it over and over again as reference.

Comment: been reading it today and still making it a reference for my angular firebase web app